# How can I copy value from one row into another row using a key?

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to copy one value into a row from another row based on key values. In the table I've included is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

This is incredibly easy to do in Excel (using xlookup) but I'm having difficulty doing this in Power Query. The problem is, I need to do this for an entire dataset with more rows that Excel can handle. And I don't have the skills to accomplish something like this in Python, so I'm stuck with Power Query for now.

How can I go about accomplishing in an efficient way?

Currently, I have two separate keys (in two columns) called 'CurrentMonthKey' and 'PreviousMonthKey' which is just a concatenation of all the different characteristics and the relevant month for each key. Column H is the column I am trying to populate.

Essentially, where row B has a 'PreviousMonthKey' that matches row A's 'CurrentMonthKey' I'd like to pull in row A's sales value into a new column in row B. Each key should be unique, so there shouldn't be more than one 'PreviousMonthKey' and 'CurrentMonthKey' match. (Very unsure if I've explained this well enough...).

I have tried merging the table with itself, and then expanding the Total Sales data from the merged column. This looked like it worked, but the exploded in size.

I also tried using this code (which I don't fully understand) but this also seemed to cause a massive growth in the load size.

```
CopyFactValue = Table.AddColumn(Total_Spent, "Previous_Month_Total_Spent", 
    each if [ParsingColumn] = "b" then
    let 
    CurrentMonthKey = [CurrentMonthKey]
    in
    List.First(Table.SelectRows(Total_Spent, each [LastMonthKey] = CurrentMonthKey)[Total_Spent])
    else null),
```

I'm hoping I've added enough context, but please let me know if more is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Merging on top of itself should work fine if keys are unique. After the merge, click on the output column and see how many rows are being returned in each table for that row. Should just be one.

[image]

**MERGING**

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type), //only needed to preserve sort, can be removed
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index", {"Last_Month_Key"}, #"Added Index", {"Current_Month_Key"}, "xxx", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "xxx", {"Sales"}, {"OldSales"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Table1",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}), //only needed to preserve sort, can be removed
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

**ALTERNATE**

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom",  (x)=>try Table.SelectRows(Source, each x[Last_Month_Key]=[Current_Month_Key])[Sales]{0} otherwise null)
in  #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and the alternative solution! I'll play around with the merge again to see if for some reason there is more than one key, and that is why the query is growing so large.

I'll also try the alternative solution to see if that works better for me. Either way, I appreciate the response and will let you know if these solve the issue.

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so please toggle the checkmark to mark question as solved